TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'jest'
I am attempting to run Jest tests in my project, however I keep getting the error
   src/tests/options.controller.test.ts:198:35 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'jest'.

    198       (mongoose as any).connect = jest.fn();

If I run I get npx tsc --traceResolution
error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'jest'.
  The file is in the program because:
    Entry point of type library 'jest' specified in compilerOptions

  tsconfig.json:7:15
    7     "types": ["jest","node"],
                    ~~~~~~
    File is entry point of type library specified here.

My tsconfig.json looks like
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2021",
    "lib": ["es2021", "esnext.asynciterable", "DOM"],
    "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"],
    "types": ["jest","node"],
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "pretty": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "allowJs": true,
    "noEmit": false,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["*"],
      "@config": ["config"],
      "@controllers/*": ["controllers/*"],
      "@databases": ["databases"],
      "@exceptions/*": ["exceptions/*"],
      "@interfaces/*": ["interfaces/*"],
      "@middlewares/*": ["middlewares/*"],
      "@models/*": ["models/*"],
      "@routes/*": ["routes/*"],
      "@services/*": ["services/*"],
      "@utils/*": ["utils/*"],
      "@mappers/*": ["mappers/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*", "test/**/*"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "src/http", "src/logs"]
}

I have tried all the solutions but no luck and I can't see why it won't resolve Jest.
I've also tried adding import '@types/jest'; in my test file but no luck
